# Loop through nested json object

Tags: javascript

My json object is

```
"lastModifyingUser": {
"kind": "drive#user",
"displayName": string,
"picture": {
  "url": string
},
"isAuthenticatedUser": boolean,
"permissionId": string
```

}

I want to loop through lastModifyingUser and pull only the url value from the picture object.

Is this possible?

here is what I have so far.

```
var obj = resp.lastModifyingUser;


                for(var k in obj){
                    var value = obj[k];
                    console.log(value);
                }
```

output :

```
drive#user 
#Hidden Name
Object {url: "#Hidden URL"}  <-- I want only the "hidden" URL
false 
#Hidden Id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursive function would more elegant, but the following should work:

```
for(var k in obj) {
    var value = obj[k];
    if (typeof value === 'object') {
        for (var k2 in value) {
            var value2 = value[k2];
            console.log(value2);
        }
    } else {
        console.log(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
for(var k in obj)
{
    var value = obj[k].url || obj[k];
    console.log(value);
}
```

will do what you want, but bear in mind it's a quick and dirty solution.  You'd probably want to some kind of basic type checking and [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) checks to make sure you're not going to throw errors or pull in prototype fields accidentally (unlikely if this is json straight from an API, but it's still a good idea to do it).